# Checbox with filter datatable

Tags: checkbox, filter, datatable

When I write something in search filter, and click checbox to check all, it checks each row regardless of the filter entered. What should I do to have the checbox check only those rows that follow the written filter, if the filter is written?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I clicked the checkbox that marks all the elements, how can I check if a word is entered in the search filter, and if so check only those elements that match the filter, otherwise check all